# MVC Radio Button List Grid

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I've got an issue trying to read the selected values from the radio button list in my [HttpPost] Controller. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Sample View]

My models are the following:

```
public partial class RoleModel
{
    public Guid RoleId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<RoleModuleAccessRight> RoleModuleAccessRights { get; set; }
}

public class RoleModuleAccessRight
{
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public bool HasFullControl { get; set; }
    public bool HasReadOnly { get; set; }
    public bool HasNoAccess { get; set; }
}
```

My Controllers:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id)
    {
        RoleModel role = BusinessLayer.UserManager.GetRoleModel(id);

        role.RoleModuleAccessRights = BusinessLayer.UserManager.GetModulesForRoleId(role.RoleId);
        return PartialView("_Edit", role);
    }

[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(RoleModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            BusinessLayer.UserManager.UpdateAccessRights(model);
            string url = Url.Action("List", "Roles");
            return Json(new { success = true, url = url });
        }
        return PartialView("_Edit", model);
    }
```

My View code:

```
@foreach (RoleModuleAccessRight item in Model.RoleModuleAccessRights)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ModuleId)
                string radioName = string.Format("RoleModuleAccessRights_{0}", item.ModuleId.ToString());
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.ModuleName</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.RadioButton(radioName, item.HasFullControl, item.HasFullControl)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.RadioButton(radioName, item.HasReadOnly, item.HasReadOnly)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.RadioButton(radioName, item.HasNoAccess, item.HasNoAccess)
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

The issue im having is that when i post the form im not able to grab the information in my [HttpPost] Controller. It returns "null"
[image]

The mark up generated is the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, your ids are not unique which is going to break things, also using a dedicated template will simplify your problem. See this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/7668325

Another more generic article: [Multiple radio button groups in MVC 4 Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174475/multiple-radio-button-groups-in-mvc-4-razor)